# JavaFX Maven Plugin deploy .deb instead .exe file

Tags: java, windows, maven, javafx, deployment

I use [JavaFX Maven Plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) to deploy my app. I want deploy Self-Contained Application for Windows, but I get **.deb** file. I use Ubuntu and my pom.xml is following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.4</version>
    <configuration>
       <mainClass>main.App</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How to set configuration to deploy **.exe** file? And how to set 32-bit os suppotring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this.

Basically, you can't create a JavaFX Self-Contained Application file targeted for a different OS, using your OS.

If you want to :

- Create an EXE/MSI, run the JavaFX packager on Windows.
- Create a DMG, run the JavaFX packager on Mac OS.
- Create a DEB, run the JavaFX packager on a Debian OS.

Comment: Really? That seems like a serious flaw - this means a developer must have a dedicated build machine for each platform they want to provide a package for...

Comment: @ItachiUchiha what means **<bundler>mac.app</bundler>**?

Comment: @ArtemGunkin If you read the [bundler section](http://javafx-maven-plugin.github.io/), you will find the following statement - *Specify the used bundler found by selected bundleType. May not be installed your OS and will fail in that case.* which mean that you cannot bundle a different type of package.

Comment: @ArtemGunkin Just want the official Oracle-documentation being referenced here: ["Package per target platform"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#A1307236) - this means that the javapackager must be seen as some small wrapper around native installed toolings